# How to wait for the dd command to finish copying before continuing my script?

Tags: linux, scripting, dd

Title pretty much nailed it, Im copying files to a flash drive and then doing some things to those files. Well I have noticed that after running the dd command the flash drive is still flashing and not all the files are on the device.

Does anyone know how to maybe run a simple loop (in script) to wait on the dd process to finish? I have been googling for about 2-3 hours now trying to figure it out and its beyond me if its even possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using dd to copy files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are seeing the operating system caching the writes.  If you really want to make sure that everything is written to the flash drive so that it is safe to remove, it needs to be unmounted.

Comment: So are you saying that the umount command will wait for the cached writes to be complete?

Comment: Yes, the umount command won't return until everything is written, including all metadata and journaled information.

Comment: However, `umount` is no help if you are using `dd` to write directly to a block device.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `sync` command:

> `sync` writes any data buffered in memory out to disk.  This can
>   include (but is not limited to) modified superblocks, modified inodes,
>   and delayed reads and writes.  This must be implemented by the kernel;
>   The `sync` program does nothing but exercise the `sync` system call.
>
> The kernel keeps data in memory to avoid doing (relatively slow)
>   disk reads and writes.  This improves performance, but if the computer
>   crashes, data may be lost or the file system corrupted as a result.
>   The `sync` command ensures everything in memory is written to disk.